# Multiple middleware has permittion on same routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.1

I have multi middleware (studen, parent, admin) and create some route group with that middleware. But some route can access if user is in any of that groups and belong in any of that middleware but not if is in other middleware fot example teacher. I use something like that in docs: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-groups But it's work when I put one route, when add another route group with another middleware it doesn't work. Is that possible and how to make it?

When I execute php artisan route it gives me an error

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Call to a member function inRole() on null
```

Comment: Please paste the code of your middleware where you run the inRole() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel's **route middleware** is executed one by one as declared in **routes.php** file. Therefore, if one of them denies access by throwing an exception or returning some respoise, the next middlewares won't be executed.

In order to make that work, you'll need a single middleware that would check if current user has any of required roles. Luckily, as of **Laravel 5.1** you are able to pass parameters to middleware from your **routes.php** file (see http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#middleware-parameters), so you'll only need one middleware class to handle all cases.

Example middleware class could look like that:

```
class HasAnyRole
{
  public function handle($request, Closure $next, $roles)
  {
    // Return Not Authorized error, if user has not logged in
    if (!$request->user) {
      App::abort(401);
    }

    $roles = explode(',', $roles);
    foreach ($roles as $role) {
      // if user has given role, continue processing the request
      if ($request->user->hasRole($role)) {
        return $next($request);
      }
    }
    // user didn't have any of required roles, return Forbidden error
    App::abort(403);
  }  
}
```

Register the middleware in your **Kernel.php**:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
  'has_any_role' => 'App\Http\Middleware\HasAnyRole',
];
```

Now, in your **routes.php** you can apply the middleware to a group like that:

```
//this route is available only to users with role admin or author
Route::put('post/{id}', ['middleware' => 'has_any_role:admin,author', function ($id) {
    //
}]);
```

This should do the trick, just make sure that your **User** class has a **hasRole** method.

Comment: TNX @jedrzej.kurylo. This is the best answer that I ever get in stack! THANK YOU!
Still have error when list route, maybe because I use sentinel package, but I didn't see error but I try to find it out. TNX.

Comment: It's OK I find a problem...in controller I used if(Sentiel::hasRole('student') and it's work when I put before that if(!Sentiel::gest()). Thank you @jedrzej.kurylo. You are the best!